# C# WPF Binding of group boxes and controls inside dependent on object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of objects in my mainViewmodel. When selecting in the listbox, depending on the selected type, a groupbox for this type should be visible and the properties should be binded.
I am not sure how i can achive this. I tried some stuff but i dont get it worked.
Foreach type of the ISimulator i have a groupbox and when I select it in the listbox, i try to show the right groupbox and bind the properties to that.

Thanks in advance
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ControlCenter.Simulators.Gui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        DataContext="MainViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="1000">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
        <Button Content="Add Simulator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" />
        <GroupBox x:Name="gb_Vehicle" Header="{Binding SimulatorId}" Margin="177,0,10,0" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Grid Height="402" Margin="10,0,12,0">
                <Label Content="StartCoordinates(x,y)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_Radius_Header" Content="Radius" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Margin="21,91,0,0"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_Freq_Header" Content="Frequency" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="21,159,0,0"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_DeltaT_Header" Content="Delta T" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="21,213,0,0"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_Velocity_Header" Content="Velocity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Cord_X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.XCord, ElementName=lb_Vehicles,Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Cord_Y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51"  Text="{Binding SelectedItem.YCord, ElementName=lb_Vehicles,Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Radius" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,122,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Radius, ElementName=lb_Vehicles,Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_DealtaT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,244,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DeltaT, ElementName=lb_Vehicles,Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Freq" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,183,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Frequency, ElementName=lb_Vehicles,Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Velocity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,309,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Velocity, ElementName=lb_Vehicles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                <WpfPlot Name="Plot" Margin="292,2,10,-2"/>
                <Button x:Name="bt_Start" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" Height="26" />
                <Button x:Name="bt_pos" Content="Draw" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="77" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="gb_Traffic" Header="{Binding SimulatorId}" Margin="177,0,10,0" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label Content="Traffic Light Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label Content="Position (x,y)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Traffic_X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,162,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="x" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_Traffic_Y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,196,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="y" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
                <Label Content="PhasePlan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
                <ListView d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Margin="220,86,10,127">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="OrderId" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Color"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="TotalDuration"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="BlinkDuration"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Action"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Button x:Name="bt_LoadConfig" Content="Load Config" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="524,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.044,-0.116" Width="107"/>
                <GroupBox Header="New Phase" Margin="10,313,189,20">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Content="Color" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,6,0,35" Height="30" Width="73"/>
                        <Label Content="Total Duration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,10,0,31" Height="30" Width="110"/>
                        <Label Content="Blink Duration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="341,7,0,34" Height="30" Width="110"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_TrafficColor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tb_TotalDuration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tb_BlinkDuration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="341,39,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                        <Button x:Name="bt_AddPhase" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="489,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62"/>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
                <Button x:Name="bt_SaveConfig" Content="Save Config" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="651,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.044,-0.116" Width="107"/>
                <Button x:Name="bt_StartTraffic" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="669,397,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="gb_AddSimulator" Header="Add Simulator" Margin="190,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible">
            <Grid Margin="10,0,21,0">
                <Label x:Name="tb_ObjectId_Header" Content="ObjectId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_ObjectId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,66,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=SimulatorModel.Config.ObjectID, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_IPAdress_Header" Content="IPAdress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_IPAdress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=SimulatorModel.Config.IpAddress, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_PortTCP_Header" Content="Port TCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_PortUDP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,169,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=SimulatorModel.Config.PortUDP, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_PortTCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=SimulatorModel.Config.PortTCP, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_PortGrpc_Header_" Content="Port GRPC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tb_PortGrpc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,169,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=SimulatorModel.Config.PortGRPC, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_PortUDP_Header1" Content="Port UDP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button x:Name="bt_Add" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,240,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Command="{Binding AddSimulatorCommand}" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="cb_SimulatorType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label x:Name="tb_PortGrpc_Header__Copy" Content="Simulator Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb_Simulators" d:ItemsSource="{Binding  }" Margin="0,94,818,10"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          
           
            var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(_logger);
            this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
           mainViewModel.SimulatorModels = new List<SimulatorModel>()
            {
                new SimulatorModel("1", null, null),
                new SimulatorModel("2", null, null),
                new SimulatorModel("3", null, null),
            };
            //lb_Simulators.ItemsSource = mainViewModel.SimulatorModels;
            //lb_Simulators.DisplayMemberPath = "ID";
            //gb_AddSimulator.DataContext = mainViewModel.SimulatorModel.Config;
            //_logger.Information("Gui startet");
        }

       


        private void SetGroupBox(GroupBoxNames name, ISimulator simulator)
        {
            gb_Vehicle.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            gb_Traffic.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            gb_AddSimulator.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            switch (name)
            {
                case GroupBoxNames.AddSimulator:
                    gb_AddSimulator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                   
                    
                    break;
                case GroupBoxNames.Traffic:
                    gb_Traffic.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    gb_Traffic.DataContext = simulator;
                    break;
                case GroupBoxNames.Vehicle:
                    gb_Vehicle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    gb_Vehicle.DataContext = simulator;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
```

MainViewModel:

```
private ILogger _logger;
        public IList<SimulatorModel> SimulatorModels { get; set; }
        public SimulatorModel SimulatorModel { get; set; }
        public ISimulator Simulator { get; set; }

        public ICommand AddSimulatorCommand;
        public ICommand RemoveSimulatorCommand;
        public ICommand LoadSimulatorConfigCommand;
        public ICommand SaveSimulatorConfigCommand;
        public ICommand AddPhaseCommand;
        public ICommand AddStartSimulatorCommand;

        public bool CanStart { get; private set; } = true;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

SimulatorModel: 
 public class SimulatorModel
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public SimulatorConfigModel Config { get; set; }
        public ISimulator Simulator { get; set; }

        public SimulatorModel(string id,SimulatorConfigModel configModel, ISimulator simulator)
        {
            ID = id;
            Config = configModel;
            Simulator = simulator;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need dynamic data type based views you usually have to define a `DataTemplate` for each. Using the `DataTemplate` makes manual control of the `GroupBox.Visibility` obsolete and significantly reduces lines of code related to the related logic. See [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

The following example shows how to display a dedicated `GroupBox` based on three imaginary `ISimulator` implementations: `SimulatorA`, `SimulatorB` and `SimulatorC`.
The associated `GroupBox` itself is hosted in a `DataTemplate` - one for each `ISimulator` implementation.
A `ContentControl` is used to render the `DataTemplate`.  `ContentControl.Comtent` is bound to the `SimulatorModel.Simulator` property i.e. the `ISimulator` instance of the currently selected item of the `ListBox`:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SimulatorA}">
      <GroupBox x:Name="gb_Vehicle">
        ...
      </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SimulatorB}">
      <GroupBox x:Name="gb_Traffic">
        ...
      </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SimulatorC}">
      <GroupBox x:Name="gb_AddSimulator">
        ...
      </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="SimulatorList" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding SimulatorModels}" />

    <!-- Host for the GroupBox that is rendered via DataTemplate
         based on the SimulatorModel.Simulator property. 
         Instead of binding directly to the ListBox.SelectedItem like below, 
         you can bind to a MainViewModel.SelectedSimulatorModel property, which is bound to the ListBox.SelectedItem -->
    <ContenControl Content="{Binding ElementName=SimulatorList, Path=SelectedItem.Simulator}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

You should bind the `ListBox`, or XAML elements in general, rather than assigning values explicitly in code-behind. Especially in an MVVM scenario where you always focus on the data models rather than on the view's elements: you only update the data model and let the framework take care of the GUI via data binding. If you have to update the source collection dynamically, make the source collection e.g., `SimulatorModels` of type `ObservableCollectio<T>`.